# How to parse the below xml in android?

Tags: android, xml

I'm having a xml as mentioned below.

```
<labels> 
    <label id="lblMS">
        <text language="EN" value="Morning Sync"/>
        <text language="DE" value="Morgan Sync"/>
    </label>
    <label id="lblES">
        <text language="EN" value="Evening Sync"/>
        <text language="DE" value="Sync Abend"/>
    </label>
    <label id="lblAS">
        <text language="EN" value="Afternoon Sync"/>
        <text language="DE" value="Sync Afternoon"/>
    </label>
</labels>
```

I can able to parse using the xmlpull parser node by node as shown below.

```java
private HashMap<String, String> readCountry(XmlPullParser parser) 
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{   
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "label");
    String labelid = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "id");
    String textlan = "";
    String textval="";
    String capital="";
    String currencyCode="";
    String currency="";

    while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
        if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
            continue;
        }

        String name = parser.getName();
         if(name.equals("text")){
             textlan = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "language");
             textval = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"value");
            readCapital(parser);
        }else{
            skip(parser);
        }
    }

    String details =    "Language : " + textlan + "\n" +
                        "Value : " + textval + "\n";


    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("id", labelid);
    hm.put("details",details);       

    return hm;
}
```

But my requirement is little different. I want make the label which contains id as the key and all the child nodes ie. text nodes as the value for the label id.

I'm struggling a lot to do this. Could you please help me in this regard.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution-

Add the Hashmap to ArrayList. So you will have a list of hashmaps in the format of "key" : "value" type.

```
private HashMap<String, String> readCountry(XmlPullParser parser) 
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{   
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "label");
    String labelid = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "id");
    String textlan = "";
    String textval="";
    String capital="";
    String currencyCode="";
    String currency="";

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap> al=new ArrayList<HashMap>();

    while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
        if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
            continue;
        }

        String name = parser.getName();
         if(name.equals("text")){
             textlan = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "language");
             textval = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"value");
            readCapital(parser);

            String details =    "Language : " + textlan + "\n" +
                        "Value : " + textval + "\n";
            hm.put(labelid, details);
            al.add(hm);
        }else{
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    someArray = compareXMLValues(timeSessionId,al);
    //return al;
    return someArray;
}



compareXMLValues(timeSessionId,al)
{
    parse full XML of syncgroupsettings;
    And compare if (timeSessionId == parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "labelid"))
    {
    if it is true-
    read from while loop, syncgroupname and store in Array list of Strings.
    }
    else
    {
    continue;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have another requirement. Please find the xml as below.

Comment: <syncgroupsettings>
    <syncgroupset id = "sgMS" labelid = "lblMS" enabled = "YES" default = "OFF">
        <syncgroup syncgroupname = "VISITS"/>
        <syncgroup syncgroupname = "CUSTOMERS"/>
    </syncgroupset>
    
    <syncgroupset id = "sgAS" labelid = "lblAS" enabled = "YES" default = "ON">
        <syncgroup syncgroupname = "SALESDOCS"/>
        <syncgroup syncgroupname = "ANALYTICS"/>
    </syncgroupset>
</syncgroupsettings>

Comment: I want to compare this labelid with the previous labelid and if it is a  match, i need to display the syn group names accordingly.
Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
hm.put("id", labelid);
hm.put("details",details);
```

with

```
hm.put(labelid, details);
```

Comment: Hey Cody, Thanks. But i'm getting only the last vlaue of the text node. i.e. only DE as language and Morgan Sync as value. Im not getting EN and morning sync